# Past/after when talking about time

Tags: time

> I'll talk to you tomorrow morning past 11.
>
> I'll talk to you tomorrow morning after 11.

Do both of them mean the same? Are both grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to sound quite right if you say `past 11`. It is better to say:

> I'll talk to you tomorrow morning after 11.

You could also say:

> I'll talk to you tomorrow morning, between 11am and 12 noon.

Answer (score 0):

When we use "past", we typically specify an actual amount:

> The sun should set at **half** *past five*.

This means that the sun will set at half an hour after 5, or 5:30. You can't just use any number there. Your options are "half" or "quarter."

"After" doesn't have this requirement of time specification, so we can say

> The sun should set after five.

OR

> The sun should set half an hour after five.

Both of these are valid and correct.

So no, the way your first sentence is written right now, it is not correct. This one, however, is correct:

> I'll talk to you tomorrow morning after 11.

Comment: No, that's completely wrong. You can of course say "I'll meet you at twenty past five", "I'll meet you at twenty to six" and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Araucaria Sure. I guess technically, those are correct. But I encourage you to look at the Ngram for "twenty past five" and compare to other options - not used very often. Idiomatically, we like "half past" or "quarter past." "To" is used more often with numerical values.

Comment: That's not very sensible, because a) 5pm is more common that 5.05, for example. Second "ten past five" is not something we write it's something we say. Thirdly ten past five is a thousand times more common in speech that *an hour after five*. Here is an Ngram showing than *apple* is a lot more common than *bananas*: [Pointless Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bananas%2Capple&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbananas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capple%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

We often say "twenty past five", "ten past five", "five past" and so on. Also, "quarter to five", "ten to five", and in some regions 'quarter of five' which does not mean 1 1/4 in this context.

However, the original sentences are grammatically correct, but the first one is not used.